# UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is called twice

Tags: objective-c, swift, uikeyboard

In my UIViewController there are two UITextField at the bottom. So on keyboard appear I'm trying to move then above. Below is my code for handling keyboard

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardHidden:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

//    MARK: - Handling Notification
func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification){
    if let initialFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        let convertedFrame = self.view.convertRect(initialFrame, fromView: nil)

        iY = viewLogin.frame.origin.y

        var currentFrame = viewLogin.frame
        currentFrame.origin.y = convertedFrame.origin.y - 140
        self.viewLogin.frame = currentFrame
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in

        })
    }
}


func keyboardHidden(notification: NSNotification){
    var currentFrame = viewLogin.frame
    currentFrame.origin.y = iY
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.viewLogin.frame = currentFrame
    })
}
```

It's working fine for first UITextField. But, when I try to move to second UITextField then again keyboardShown() is called and my view move back to bottom. I'm not able to detect the actual cause. Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry. I din't get what you are asking about? I'm using UITextField delegate for resigning the keyboard using UITextField.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: I'm not using this methods of UITextFieldDelegate. I'm using keyboard notification.

Comment: if you are not using the uitextfield delegates then you should need to set a bool variable to find is the keyboard is already appeared or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to the AutoLayout. I solved it as below

```
//    MARK: - Handling Notification
func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification){
    self.bottomConstraint.constant += 125
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.viewLogin.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}


func keyboardHidden(notification: NSNotification){
    self.bottomConstraint.constant -= 125
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.viewLogin.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

We need to change the property of constraint, if we had used AutoLayout.